# File sharing using Intent.ACTION_SEND gives access denied on BBM

Tags: android, android-permissions, bb-messenger

I am trying to share an audio file saved by my application. The file is added to the media store so all apps can access it.

```
Intent mediaScannerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    Uri fileContentUri = Uri.fromFile(finalFile);
    mediaScannerIntent.setData(fileContentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScannerIntent);
```

I use Intent.ACTION_SEND to share the files to other apps:

```
public void shareRecording(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    i.setType("audio/mp3");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///" + recording.getFilePath()));
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share " + recording.getName()));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "There are no app installed to share your audio file.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

All working good with all apps like GMail, Yahoo mail, Whatsapp, ...
except BBM, it gives access denied.
What do I need to do to make it work on BBM ?

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE:**

I used

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("content://" + recording.getFilePath());
```

instead of

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("file:///" + recording.getFilePath());
```

and it worked on BBM but not othe apps

So what is the difference between havin the URI parsed with: "file:///" and "content://" ?
And how can I used this to get the share working for all apps ?

[image: Error on BBM]

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the actual file to initialize the Uri object.

```
File recordingFile = new File(recording.getFilePath());
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(recordingFile);
```

This worked with all the apps that can share a file.